# removing a class x number in a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to figure out a way to remove classes in sets of 4 within a list item.

So let's say I have an unorder list with 50 list items with 40 of the items having a class of 'hide'. I have a button that handles a click event to remove 4 of the li's hide class.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li class="hide">foo</li>
  <li class="hide">foo</li>
  <li class="hide">foo</li>
  <li class="hide">foo</li>
  <li class="hide">foo</li>
  <li class="hide">foo</li>
  <li class="hide">foo</li>
  <li class="hide">foo</li>
  <li class="hide">foo</li>
  <li class="hide">foo</li>
  <li class="hide">foo</li>
  <li class="hide">foo</li>
  <li class="hide">foo</li>
  <li class="hide">foo</li>
  <li class="hide">foo</li>
</ul>
<button>Click me to see the next 4 items</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('button').click(function () {
  $('li.hide').removeClass('hide');
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
 $('button').on('click',function() {
    $('li.hide').each(function(i) {
        if (i == 4)
            return false;
        $(this).removeClass('hide');
    });
});
```

Comment: Bad approach. [`.each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) provides an index in the callback. `function (i) { if (i < 4) $(this).removeClass('hide')}` is much better.

Comment: @royhowie suppose i have 50 div if use your condition then it'll iterate 50 div which is not efficient .. break on i==4 is not wrong as index start from 0 .. 0 -3 = 4

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I meant to add an `else return false`, but neglected to.

Answer (score 0):

use the [:lt()](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) selector:

```
$('button').click(function() {
  $('li.hide:lt(4)').removeClass('hide');
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mrub5b0z/